# How to keep checkbox checked after form submit

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to keep checkbox "checked" after form submit and page load. I have following simple code from .module file.

```
    <?php

function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['examples/my_module'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['terms'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t('Your checkbox'),
    );
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['terms']['#default_value'] = 1;
  }

?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Forms are ways for users to input data, but that data needs to be held somewhere for it to be used to generate the form. For example, when that checkbox is checked, it will relate to a setting in the DB, or maybe a SESSION variable. You would use this stored data in the form generation to determine whether the box should be checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to specify #default_value to your element, Then if you are going to save your data in some place, then load it and use it as your element default_value, if you are not going to save it then you can use form_state on that but remember to set $form_state['form_rebuild'] as TRUE in submit handler, a sample code will be like this :

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['terms'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Your checkbox'),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['terms']) ? $form_state['values']['terms'] : array(),
  );
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  );

  return $form;
}
function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['terms']['#default_value'] = 1;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```